# How to number items using Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8

There is a list.

```
List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
items.add("abcd");
items.add("efgh");
items.add("ijkl");
items.add("mnop");
```

I want to print in console with numbering

```
1. abcd
2. efgh
3. ijkl
4. mnop
```

I am beginner with Java 8. I am trying several tricks using java 8. please help.

Comment: Just use a `for( int i=0; i<items.size(); i++)` loop. No need for tricks.

Comment: The same way you would do it in Java 7: with a for loop and a counter that increments at each iteration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use an `IntStream` for the indices :

```
IntStream.range(0,items.size()).forEach(i -> 
  System.out.println((i+1) + ". " + items.get(i)));
```

Comment: If we go this way, let's go all the way. I'll upvote for a version that zips both streams and avoids the array access by index.  Upvote. Not use. For loop works just fine. :-)

Comment: This is good for learning but does not add much to readability. Streams are for more complex tasks.

Answer (score 4):

Use `for` loop if you need the numeric loop variable. You can still use `get` with list.

```
for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
  System.out.println( (i+1) + " " + items.get(i) );
}
```

Comment: @Thilo: To be nitpicking, that code requires at least Java 2 to work. Still an Oldie though

Comment: @Holger: Why is that? Collection classes were added to the standard library in 1.2, I think, but the code does not explicitly use them. Could be a third-party class.

Comment: @Thilo: if you only care for the syntax, then you’re right.